# Does news of layoff cause stock to go up or down

Tags: stocks

Does news of layoff cause stock to go up or down.  On one hand they are saving money but other hand the business is probably doing bad. Asking since META just announced layoffs.

Answer (score 2):

When there is news regarding a company, the price will probably move. The direction depends on the overall picture.

- If the market is surprised, then the price will probably drop.
- If it was expected, then the price could move in either direction, but it can also depend on does the number match what people were expecting.
- Of course if the market thought it should have been done months ago, it could cause the price to rise.